# Python using self to call function syntax

Tags: python, class

Been digging into the source code of the Python package `transformers`, saw this code and am stumped.

```
model_inputs = self.prepare_inputs_for_generation(input_ids, **model_kwargs)
outputs = self(
          **model_inputs,
          return_dict=True,
          output_attentions=output_attentions,
          output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
          )
```

What is the `self()` call doing here? Is it calling the class instance?

For reference, the source code is here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/generation/utils.py

Please read the source code on the link, this class does not have a `__call__` method implemented.

Comment: Please add enough code to understand what `self` is (e.g. the class) to the question itself.

Comment: `self` is expexted to be a callable in this case. Any class that defines a `__call__` method can use the call syntax, e.g `foo = SomeCallable(); print(foo())`. A function object is one example of a callable, a type object (i.e. a class) is another example of a callable. But you can define your own as well

Comment: " Is it calling the class instance?" Yes, precisely.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what if a `__call__` method is not implemented? I cannot find one in that class.

Comment: @KlausD. The relevant code to the class is far too big to post as a question here.

Comment: The class you link to is a mixin (its name hints at that); that means it's expected to be inherited/mixed into another class, which is probably expected to implement `__call__`.

Comment: @deceze yeah, the docstring has `A class containing all functions for auto-regressive text generation, to be used as a mixin in [`PreTrainedModel`].`